# Get Acceleration only in one direction using ACCELEROMETER

Tags: android, accelerometer

I am using SensorEventListener for geting gravity..
But I want Gravity only x-direction.. 
What I do for geting acceleration value only in X-direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific from the answer from Rajnikant, look here :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values

values[0] gives you the acceleration on the X-axis...

Comment: Just adding here, there is no way to get the system to only hand you X-direction acceleration -- you will have to dig it out yourself.

Comment: Maybe for some weird device with a one-axis accelerometer... then the values[1] and [2] may be garbage. But I don't see why anybody woud do such a thing and what's the big deal about extracting one component out of the three you get (?)

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) under Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER section.